# When is it a good practice to use worker pool in Golang?

Tags: go, concurrency, threadpool, worker

As far as I know, when it comes to Golang people mostly use worker (goroutine) pools to limit concurrency in one way or another.

After the addition of [`errgroup.SetLimit`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20220929204114-8fcdb60fdcc0/errgroup#Group.SetLimit) into the standard library this summer, which:

> *limits the number of active goroutines in this group to at most `n`*

**are now worker pool patterns redundant in most cases**?

If they aren't, what would be a good example where a worker pool pattern is still preferred over using `errgroup.SetLimit` or pure goroutines?

Comment: When the performance of your programme can benefit from mutualising some upfront computation and when workers don't hold on to prohibitively large references to stuff on the heap, worker pools remain a good option in comparison to using a semaphore.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the input @jub0bs! It's still not quite clear to be when should you use one or the other though. Are they (worker pool vs goroutines with semaphores) just mostly a matter of personal preference then? Or what would be a good example where one might benefit from using one over the other?

Comment: If you need to regularly change the number of concurrent routines based on some dynamic information (feedback?), this abstraction looks like it might not be appropriate.